# cannot read last line from console using scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This question is already asked, but I am not clear with the answers.
Please check my code below. I am pasting multiple lines in console without pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> button. `Scanner` is not reading the last line, but when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> it reads it.

My input is:

> 2
>   4 3
>   -1 -3 4 2
>   4 2
>   0 -1 2 1

Output with out enter:

> 243-1-34242

When I press enter it is showing last line.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print(scan.next());
    }
}
```

Please try in Eclipse.

Comment: try using `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()`

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.print(scan.nextLine());` instead .

Comment: And then parse the line

Answer (score 0):

You may also use BufferedReader to read each line and parse to get the `int`s (if you want) -

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;

while ((line = input.readLine()) != null && line.length()!= 0) {
    String[] ints = line.split(" "); //ints contains all integers only 
                                     //for the current line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the problem. Anyway...

Your data sample contains a line feed at the end of each line which tells the Scanner that the line is over (except for the last line). You should either add a line feed to the last line or press enter to tell the Scanner that the input has ended.